# React changes the sequence of CSS rules applied after the deployment to remote

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a page with a resizable panel on the bottom using `react-resize-panel` lib.
I had to change the alignment of the elements inside the `div`s generated by the `<ResizePanel>` component provided by the lib.

`<ResizePanel>` creates three levels of elements:
[image: generated HTML elements]

I needed to override the `margin-bottom` property of the child with the class name *ResizePanel-module_ResizeBarVertical__2LUZV*. Likely, the suffix is generated dynamically, so I had to use the CSS selector to override it:

```
[class^='ResizePanel-module_ResizeBarVertical'] {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Tested it locally and it worked as expected. But when I deployed to remote the sequence of the CSS rules applied changed and my custom style was overridden:
[image: local and remote styles]

I would like to get a better understanding of how CSS is loaded locally and remotely. In particular, is there any rule of thumb for local testing when it comes to React styles and conflicting CSS rules

**UPDATE with solution**

There are two solutions suitable:

1. narrow down the selector to div only (selected this one based on best practices)

```
div[class^='ResizePanel-module_ResizeBarVertical'] {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

2. use !important in the style

```
[class^='ResizePanel-module_ResizeBarVertical'] {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS Precedence could be tricky sometimes, there should be 3 "levels", sorted by highest priority:

1. **!important** (you can force override; should solve your problem, but probably doesn't fully answer your question)
2. **specification of selector** (how much specified the selector is; seems like what you are struggling with – your custom selector is less specified, so it has lower weight)
3. **order; what was declarated first** (there could also be problem with cache; but that's probably not your case)

More info about the selector specificity weight in the Mozilla docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: That's right. I've added how I solved the issue. I wonder why does local env differs from the remote though